# Blur not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, primeng

I'm trying to apply blur effect on dialog pop-up.

I'm using primeng p-dialog component.

```
<p-panelMenu [model]="items" [style]="{'width':'300px'}"></p-panelMenu>

<p-dialog header="HELLO" [(visible)]="display" modal="modal" [responsive]="true" [width]="350" [minWidth]="200" (onHide)="close($event)" >
    <span>hi</span>

</p-dialog>
```

In CSS I apply blur effect

```
::ng-deep .ui-widget-overlay {
      filter: blur(20px);
}
```

The problem is that the blur effect is not working as expected.

Actually I have a "glow" effect ([see demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dialogue?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)) and not real blur effect like [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur)

Comment: .ui-widget-overlay {
    background: rgba(102, 102, 102,0.5);
    opacity: 1;}

Comment: added it to my example , doesn't work

Comment: did you change both background and opacity ?

Comment: @peinearydevelopment I'm trying to blur every that is on the background of the dialog box. ( in the example, file button should get blurred )

Comment: @paragparmmar I have added your code to the css.

Comment: I was trying to make the blur effect. Now I should apply it only if  dialog box is open, any idea how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

I should Wrap the content that I should blur in a div then apply to it the effect when the pdiaog is expended  using `ngclass`

```
<div [class.container]="display">
  <p-panelMenu [model]="items" [style]="{'width':'300px'}"></p-panelMenu>

</div>
<p-dialog header="HELLO" [(visible)]="display" modal="modal" [responsive]="true" [width]="350" [minWidth]="200" (onHide)="close($event)" >
    <span>hi</span>

</p-dialog>
```

In **CSS**

```
.container {
  filter: blur(3px);
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dialogue-g28cyh?file=app/app.component.css)